# Orbits of $SL(3, \mathbb{C})/B$

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $B=  \Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}
* & *&* \\
0 & *&*\\
0&0&*
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg\}< SL(3,\mathbb C)$. What is $SL(3,\mathbb C)/B$?

Do we use these facts:

- Borel fixed point theorem.
- Algebraic actions of unipotent groups are cells $U_-\cdot x_0=U_-/H$?

I actually need a detailed solution because I don't have enough background in this subject and I have to understand it! Any solutions or comments are highly appreciated as well.

I also need to know the basic definitions and examples in flag manifolds which are essential to the solution. Particularity, in matrices case.

Comment: Notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety

Comment: Thanks anon. I'd be grateful if you write down the answer with the basic details. I know it is maybe silly, but I need to understand everything. Thanks again

Comment: What exactly do you mean by computing ${\rm SL}(3,\Bbb C)/B$?

Comment: actions of $B$ in $SL(3,\mathbb C)$

Comment: Huh? Are you trying to find some more familiar homeomorphism type for the space ${\rm SL}(3,\Bbb C)$? I am not sure if there is one. Of course, whenever $X$ is a homogeneous space with respect to $G$, with a closed point-stabilizer $H$, we can say $X\cong G/H$ as spaces - in particular the complete flag manifold over $\Bbb C$ is homogeneous with respect to ${\rm SL}(3,\Bbb C)$ with isotropy subgroup $B$, so there's that. What do you want from your readers?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not clear, but actually I am myself confused! But I understand that $SL(2,\mathbb C)/\begin{bmatrix}
* & * \\
0 & *
\end{bmatrix} = \mathbb P^1$ so I need the calculation in  3-dim

Comment: I mean I don't know the calculation in the 3-dim case. Maybe I should change the question to find the isotropy !!

Comment: I am not asking if you know the calculation, I am asking what you *mean* by the word calculation. I don't understand what you mean by "find the isotropy" ... isotropy is just another word for stabilizer.

Comment: Okay, I mean what is (how to find) the quotient space (group)  $SL(3,\mathbb C)/B$ Where $B$ is the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $SL(3,\mathbb C)$?

Comment: Could you please explain (for the benefit of potential responders) why you so urgently need a detailed argument to a technical question for which you don't have the necessary background or understand the basic examples? The question sounds like part of an end-of-course exam or large-scale course project, and unfortunately, the more times I re-read this post and comments, the harder it becomes to believe the question was asked in good faith. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Yes you are right, I know it is a technical question. The point is that I need the minimal  theory  to understand up to this point.

Comment: It is a seminar in flag manifolds, and I have to understand these thing quickly which they will be the next subject next week, and I don't like to be foolish in the seminar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anon gave a good reference. It suffices to read it!

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dim $n$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be a
basis. A complete flag $V\in\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is:
$\{0\}=V_0\subset V_1\subset\cdots V_n=\mathbb{C}^n$ where
$dim(V_i)=i$. Note that $GL_n$ acts of $\mathcal{F}$ in a natural way.
If $V_S$ is the standard flag associated to $\mathcal{B}$, then $f\in
Gl_n$ satisfies $f(V_S)=V_S$ iff $f\in T_n$ (the upper triangular
invertible matrices); moreover if $V,W\in \mathcal{F}$, then there is
$f\in GL_n$ s.t. $f(V)=W$. Thus the variety $\mathcal{F}$ is the
homogeneous space $GL_n/T_n$ of dimension $n^2-n(n+1)/2=n(n-1)/2$ over
$\mathbb{C}$ and $n^2-n$ over $\mathbb{R}$; that is the same set than
your space $SL_n/B_n$. We can see also $V_{i+1}$ as $V_i\bigoplus
u_{i+1}$ where $u_{i+1}$ is a unitary vector orthogonal to $V_i$. Note
that $u_i$ is defined up to a mult. with an element of $S^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then the
standard flag associated to the orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B}$ is in $U(n)$ and its
stabilizer is the set of diagonal matrices in $(S^1)^n=\tau_n$, the $n$-torus.
Finally our set is the compact real homogeneous space $U(n)/\tau_n$; we find again that its dimension is $n^2-n$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

When $n=2$, we obtain $P^1(\mathbb{C})$ which is homeomorphic to $S^2(\mathbb{R})$.

When $n=3$, we obtain $\{(u,v)\in P^2(\mathbb{C})\times P^2(\mathbb{C})|u\perp v\}$ that has dimension $4+4-2=6$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT. In other words, when $n=3$, a complete flag $F$ is given by $V_1,V_2$ or by an orthonormal basis $(u_1,u_3,u_3)$ of $\mathbb{C}^3$ s.t. $u_1\in V_1,u_2\in V_2$. Then a representative of $F$ is $A=[u_1,u_2,u_3]\in U(3)$. If $B$ is another representative of $F$, then $B=Adiag(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2},e^{i\theta_3})$.

Comment: Thanks! but in case $n=3$ can we write the set in an explicit way. I mean as a disjoint union of some sets?

Comment: I don't think so. I think that the variety is irreducible. Anyway, a flag is the equivalence class of some $U\in U(n)$: $\{Udiag((e^{i\theta_j})_j)|(\theta_j)_j\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$.

Comment: loup blanc: I wonder how to get from $SL_n/B_n$ to $U(n)/\tau_n$? Or they are different approaches? Moreover, I need more details when $n=3$ please .. thanks

Comment: @ loup blanc, sorry, but I still don't understand how you deduced the space when n=3 $\{(u,v)\in P^2(\mathbb{C})\times P^2(\mathbb{C})|u\perp v\}$ and how you calculate the dimension $4+4-2=6$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The flag is defined by two orthogonal vectors $u\in V_1,v\in V_2$. Generically $u=a[u_1,u_2,1]^T,v=b[v_1,v_2,1]^T$ with the condition (C) $\bar{u_1}v_1+\bar{u_2}v_2+1=0$. $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$ depend on $4+4$ real parameters and the condition (C) removes two real parameters.