# Schubert Cells of Flags

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, schubert-calculus

I have been reading on these notes [Undergraduate Lectures on Flag Varieties](http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/PCMI15/Introduction.pdf) and I need some explanations on two things:

1. In page 3, how he modefied the matrices in the "Second Attempt"
2. In the same manner, how can I get the flag $Fl(1,2,3)(\mathbb C^3)$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For 1, note that if the star in the second column and second row in the first attempt for the $\{1,3\}$ matrix is nonzero, then we can divide the row by it and obtain a matrix of the form for $\{1,2\}$. This causes overlap, and if we insist that instead that spot have a zero in it then there is no overlap. Similar arguments apply for the other matrices.

Comment: For 2, the book "Young Tableaux" by Fulton has a detailed account for the complete flag variety. Perhaps someone will write an answer but a full explanation would be lengthy.

Comment: I see this is related to a question you asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508147/orbits-of-sl3-mathbbc-b

Comment: For a quick and dirty explanantion that offers no insight, take a $3\times 3$ permutation matrix and draw a star in every unoccupied spot that is not above (in the same column) or to the right (in the same row) of any $1$. Put $0$s everywhere else. That's the Schubert cell corresponding to the permutation matrix.

Comment: @Matt, For 1, I still don't see the case {1,4}, {2,3} can you please explain it like what you did for the case {1,3} earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick and dirty explanantion that offers no insight (as requested), take a $3\times 3$ permutation matrix and draw a star in every unoccupied spot that is not above (in the same column) or to the right (in the same row) of any $1$. Put $0$s everywhere else. That's the Schubert cell corresponding to the permutation matrix.

For example, for the permutation 312 (which has length $2$, so the cell should have codimension $2$, dimension $1$) we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\\ast&1&0\end{array}\right]$$
and for 213 (length $1$, codimension $1$, dimension $2$) we have
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\\ast&\ast&1\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. However if I have more questions I will ask you :)

Comment: I have a question here: where we draw stars in this perm matrix $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{array}\right]$ and why?